# Cypher: how do I check that at least one of the nodes in a set matches a given property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a data model in neo4j where a Person node may be "merged" with another — not literally merged, just a relation in the form:

`(a:Person)-[:MERGED]-(other:Person)`

And, of course, `b` can be merged with someone else, in a potentially endless path.

I have a query to return a list of persons, with the 'merged' persons — that is, anyone in the `:MERGED` path — embedded as a property.

```
MATCH (a:Person)
CALL {
    WITH a
    MATCH path = (a)-[:MERGED*]-(other)
    RETURN COLLECT(other{.label}) as b
}
 RETURN a{.label, merged_items:b}
```

This returns, for example, something like:

```
{
  "label": "John Smith",
  "merged_items": [
    {
      "label": "Toby Jones"
    },
    {
      "label": "Seamus McGibbon"
    },
    {
      "label": "Aaron Drew"
    }
  ] 
}
```

for each of the Persons in this chain of merges (so actually the full result has four items, with each of the connected people being `a` — this is precisely what I want).

Now, I want to be able to *filter* the results by the `Person.label`, but **any one** of the Persons in the chain could match (either `a` OR any of the `other`s).

Any idea how I might go about this?

I've tried a lot of different things (`any()`, for example) but can't get it to work.

Comment: can you draw how john, toby, seamus and aaron are connected? then how do you want to filter by person.label? what is the result you are expecting? Can you show use your query using any()? Maybe we can fix it from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `any()` is `WHERE any(e IN list WHERE predicate(e))`

So in your case, this should work.

```
WITH  COLLECT(other{.label}) as b
WHERE any(e IN b WHERE e.label = a.label)
RETURN b
```

You could in principle already apply it to the path before you collect. The `tail(list)` is so that it excludes `a` which would be the first node of the path.

```
MATCH ...
WHERE any(n in tail(nodes(path)) WHERE n.label = a.label)
```